# Zotonic- where can a quickstart be found

Tags: zotonic

I have been to the [zotonic docs](http://zotonic.com/documentation), but well, they have not really been helpful because everything is in bits and pieces over there. I am an averagely good erlang programmer and i guess what i need is a full example of a web site or web app, however simple, but from ground up.
 Usually, an example built ground up  would be used to illustrate all the basic concepts of a library. Forexample, how is a site arranged ? how and where do i put these files ? what does this config mean ? which options are there for this task ? e.t.c. 
Zotonic looks great on the outside and i would love to dive into it. It looks like the only Erlang easy-way of building a web site and managing a web site using erlang.
**Question:**  Has anyone come across a full-fledged Zotonic-built web site or web app, whose source he can share or a tutorial coming from ground up, especially for Erlang programmers, that can get one really started ? *Something similar to this **[Django introduction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial01/)***
 Also, are there any builds for Zotonic that can install on a windows Server ?

Comment: Just want to add that the docs have been rewamped with the 0.9 release of zotonic: http://zotonic.com/docs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm developing (in my spare time, which hasn't been much lately) a project/issue tracker in zotonic. Code is available here: https://github.com/kaos/trackz and a demo site running the code here: http://trackz.astekk.se/

It's in it's early stages, so it won't be too hard to follow the progress from scratch by looking at the commits made, to that end, it's not much to look at either, yet.

It is developed against 0.8.x, so it probably won't be without issues to run it on 0.9-dev.

I also have some articles about zotonic internals (how to write modules for zotonic) and other related topics here: http://blog.astekk.se/en/by_keyword/318/zotonic

Hope this fills in at least some of your questions :)

Hint:

Study the data model and directory structure. Once you grok that, the rest will come easy.

Comment: However, there is still much to be done. Perhaps after this entire project, you could create for us an `idiots guide to Zotonic` something well arranged, similar to `learn you some Erlang for great good` :)

Comment: Indeed. I'm pondering several times a week on how to best teach/document zotonic, since that is the number 1 question new users have right now.